# Jealousy minus the resentment?

Tags: emotions

Jealousy and envy seem to have resentment tied in with them, and that's not what I'm trying to express. This is like, I want something someone else has, and I am sorry that they got it before me, but I do not resent them for it. They deserve it and I'm respectful of that, I just wish I had it.

Comment: Perhaps you could qualify your jealousy. As in "respectfully envious". You could also redirect the negativity and say you were "disappointed in your loss" which mentions no disrespect to the winner.

Comment: Duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/308296/non-malevolent-synonym-of-envy or http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/266611/whats-a-word-for-a-positive-kind-of-envy-without-the-sense-of-resentment.  There are other possible duplicates.  Type in "jealousy and envy" into the Question bar and several good duplicates come up.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps *[wistful](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/wistful)*

> Having or showing a feeling of vague or regretful longing

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*